# ui.autocomplete does not correctly display special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this ui.autocomplete JavaScript. Anytime I search for something with "&" it suggest the appropriate item but shows "`&amp;`" So let's say I search "C&A Shop".  It shows "C`&amp;`A Shop" in the Dropdown suggestion box.

I found this within the JavaScript:

```
{return a.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g,"\\$&")}
```

But it is not working, any suggestion?

The whole JavaScript is:

```
/*
 * jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.5
 *
 * Copyright 2010, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete
 *
 * Depends:
 *  jquery.ui.core.js
 *  jquery.ui.widget.js
 *  jquery.ui.position.js
 */
(function(e){e.widget("ui.autocomplete",{options:{appendTo:"body",delay:300,minLength:1,position:{my:"left top",at:"left bottom",collision:"none"},source:null},_create:function(){var a=this,b=this.element[0].ownerDocument;this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-input").attr("autocomplete","off").attr({role:"textbox","aria-autocomplete":"list","aria-haspopup":"true"}).bind("keydown.autocomplete",function(c){if(!a.options.disabled){var d=e.ui.keyCode;switch(c.keyCode){case d.PAGE_UP:a._move("previousPage",
c);break;case d.PAGE_DOWN:a._move("nextPage",c);break;case d.UP:a._move("previous",c);c.preventDefault();break;case d.DOWN:a._move("next",c);c.preventDefault();break;case d.ENTER:case d.NUMPAD_ENTER:a.menu.element.is(":visible")&&c.preventDefault();case d.TAB:if(!a.menu.active)return;a.menu.select(c);break;case d.ESCAPE:a.element.val(a.term);a.close(c);break;default:clearTimeout(a.searching);a.searching=setTimeout(function(){if(a.term!=a.element.val()){a.selectedItem=null;a.search(null,c)}},a.options.delay);
break}}}).bind("focus.autocomplete",function(){if(!a.options.disabled){a.selectedItem=null;a.previous=a.element.val()}}).bind("blur.autocomplete",function(c){if(!a.options.disabled){clearTimeout(a.searching);a.closing=setTimeout(function(){a.close(c);a._change(c)},150)}});this._initSource();this.response=function(){return a._response.apply(a,arguments)};this.menu=e("<ul></ul>").addClass("ui-autocomplete").appendTo(e(this.options.appendTo||"body",b)[0]).mousedown(function(c){var d=a.menu.element[0];
c.target===d&&setTimeout(function(){e(document).one("mousedown",function(f){f.target!==a.element[0]&&f.target!==d&&!e.ui.contains(d,f.target)&&a.close()})},1);setTimeout(function(){clearTimeout(a.closing)},13)}).menu({focus:function(c,d){d=d.item.data("item.autocomplete");false!==a._trigger("focus",null,{item:d})&&/^key/.test(c.originalEvent.type)&&a.element.val(d.value)},selected:function(c,d){d=d.item.data("item.autocomplete");var f=a.previous;if(a.element[0]!==b.activeElement){a.element.focus();
a.previous=f}if(false!==a._trigger("select",c,{item:d})){a.term=d.value;a.element.val(d.value)}a.close(c);a.selectedItem=d},blur:function(){a.menu.element.is(":visible")&&a.element.val()!==a.term&&a.element.val(a.term)}}).zIndex(this.element.zIndex()+1).css({top:0,left:0}).hide().data("menu");e.fn.bgiframe&&this.menu.element.bgiframe()},destroy:function(){this.element.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-input").removeAttr("autocomplete").removeAttr("role").removeAttr("aria-autocomplete").removeAttr("aria-haspopup");
this.menu.element.remove();e.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this)},_setOption:function(a,b){e.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments);a==="source"&&this._initSource();if(a==="appendTo")this.menu.element.appendTo(e(b||"body",this.element[0].ownerDocument)[0])},_initSource:function(){var a=this,b,c;if(e.isArray(this.options.source)){b=this.options.source;this.source=function(d,f){f(e.ui.autocomplete.filter(b,d.term))}}else if(typeof this.options.source==="string"){c=this.options.source;this.source=
function(d,f){a.xhr&&a.xhr.abort();a.xhr=e.getJSON(c,d,function(g,i,h){h===a.xhr&&f(g);a.xhr=null})}}else this.source=this.options.source},search:function(a,b){a=a!=null?a:this.element.val();this.term=this.element.val();if(a.length<this.options.minLength)return this.close(b);clearTimeout(this.closing);if(this._trigger("search")!==false)return this._search(a)},_search:function(a){this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");this.source({term:a},this.response)},_response:function(a){if(a.length){a=
this._normalize(a);this._suggest(a);this._trigger("open")}else this.close();this.element.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")},close:function(a){clearTimeout(this.closing);if(this.menu.element.is(":visible")){this._trigger("close",a);this.menu.element.hide();this.menu.deactivate()}},_change:function(a){this.previous!==this.element.val()&&this._trigger("change",a,{item:this.selectedItem})},_normalize:function(a){if(a.length&&a[0].label&&a[0].value)return a;return e.map(a,function(b){if(typeof b===
"string")return{label:b,value:b};return e.extend({label:b.label||b.value,value:b.value||b.label},b)})},_suggest:function(a){var b=this.menu.element.empty().zIndex(this.element.zIndex()+1),c;this._renderMenu(b,a);this.menu.deactivate();this.menu.refresh();this.menu.element.show().position(e.extend({of:this.element},this.options.position));a=b.width("").outerWidth();c=this.element.outerWidth();b.outerWidth(Math.max(a,c))},_renderMenu:function(a,b){var c=this;e.each(b,function(d,f){c._renderItem(a,f)})},
_renderItem:function(a,b){return e("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete",b).append(e("<a></a>").text(b.label)).appendTo(a)},_move:function(a,b){if(this.menu.element.is(":visible"))if(this.menu.first()&&/^previous/.test(a)||this.menu.last()&&/^next/.test(a)){this.element.val(this.term);this.menu.deactivate()}else this.menu[a](b);else this.search(null,b)},widget:function(){return this.menu.element}});e.extend(e.ui.autocomplete,{escapeRegex:function(a){return a.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g,"\\$&")},
filter:function(a,b){var c=new RegExp(e.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(b),"i");return e.grep(a,function(d){return c.test(d.label||d.value||d)})}})})(jQuery);
(function(e){e.widget("ui.menu",{_create:function(){var a=this;this.element.addClass("ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all").attr({role:"listbox","aria-activedescendant":"ui-active-menuitem"}).click(function(b){if(e(b.target).closest(".ui-menu-item a").length){b.preventDefault();a.select(b)}});this.refresh()},refresh:function(){var a=this;this.element.children("li:not(.ui-menu-item):has(a)").addClass("ui-menu-item").attr("role","menuitem").children("a").addClass("ui-corner-all").attr("tabindex",
-1).mouseenter(function(b){a.activate(b,e(this).parent())}).mouseleave(function(){a.deactivate()})},activate:function(a,b){this.deactivate();if(this.hasScroll()){var c=b.offset().top-this.element.offset().top,d=this.element.attr("scrollTop"),f=this.element.height();if(c<0)this.element.attr("scrollTop",d+c);else c>=f&&this.element.attr("scrollTop",d+c-f+b.height())}this.active=b.eq(0).children("a").addClass("ui-state-hover").attr("id","ui-active-menuitem").end();this._trigger("focus",a,{item:b})},
deactivate:function(){if(this.active){this.active.children("a").removeClass("ui-state-hover").removeAttr("id");this._trigger("blur");this.active=null}},next:function(a){this.move("next",".ui-menu-item:first",a)},previous:function(a){this.move("prev",".ui-menu-item:last",a)},first:function(){return this.active&&!this.active.prevAll(".ui-menu-item").length},last:function(){return this.active&&!this.active.nextAll(".ui-menu-item").length},move:function(a,b,c){if(this.active){a=this.active[a+"All"](".ui-menu-item").eq(0);
a.length?this.activate(c,a):this.activate(c,this.element.children(b))}else this.activate(c,this.element.children(b))},nextPage:function(a){if(this.hasScroll())if(!this.active||this.last())this.activate(a,this.element.children(":first"));else{var b=this.active.offset().top,c=this.element.height(),d=this.element.children("li").filter(function(){var f=e(this).offset().top-b-c+e(this).height();return f<10&&f>-10});d.length||(d=this.element.children(":last"));this.activate(a,d)}else this.activate(a,this.element.children(!this.active||
this.last()?":first":":last"))},previousPage:function(a){if(this.hasScroll())if(!this.active||this.first())this.activate(a,this.element.children(":last"));else{var b=this.active.offset().top,c=this.element.height();result=this.element.children("li").filter(function(){var d=e(this).offset().top-b+c-e(this).height();return d<10&&d>-10});result.length||(result=this.element.children(":first"));this.activate(a,result)}else this.activate(a,this.element.children(!this.active||this.first()?":last":":first"))},
hasScroll:function(){return this.element.height()<this.element.attr("scrollHeight")},select:function(a){this._trigger("selected",a,{item:this.active})}})})(jQuery);
;
```

This is in my theme-script:

```
jQuery( ".newtag" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl + "?action=ajax-tag-search-front&tax=stores",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    //alert('ERROR!: '+ errorThrown);
                    //alert('ERROR!: '+ textStatus);
                    //alert('ERROR!: '+ XMLHttpRequest);
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            term: item,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // alert (ui.item.term.slug);
            storeurl = ui.item.term.clpr_store_url;
            if (storeurl != 0) {
                jQuery(".clpr_store_url").html('<a href="' + storeurl + '" target="_blank">' + storeurl + '<br /><img src="' + ui.item.term.clpr_store_image_url + '" class="screen-thumb" /></a><input type="hidden" name="clpr_store_id" value="' + ui.item.term.term_id + '" /><input type="hidden" name="clpr_store_slug" value="' + ui.item.term.slug + '" />');
            }   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Look at this solution, it should work for you too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125333/jquery-autocomplete-and-special-characters-in-wordpress

Comment: It looks like you've posted the UI widget code but not your application code which references `autocomplete`.

Comment: Hi is this the missed code? (added it on top)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening external to the javascript.  When you make the request using ajax the server is returning valid HTML and HTML requires that such characters be expressed as entities.

You can see the actual data being returned (with the `&amp;`) in the debug console of your browser.

You can fix it one of two ways, change the data in the javascript after you receive it or change your web service (whatever you are using) to return just the ampersand.

I'd suggest the first option if you have a choice.

**edit**

I expect this would work for you locally (note use of replace function):

```
            success: function( data ) {
                response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        term: item,
                        value: item.name.replace("&amp;","&")
                    }
                }));
            }
```

Comment: can you tell me how i can change the data in the javascript??

Comment: @theo69 - be happy to if you reformat the example code so I can read it.

Comment: sorry but thats how the script is saved, didn´t change the format

Comment: @theo69 - when you debug what do you see?  how is it not working?

Comment: sorry had some other stuff to fix first, where do i put these code snippet, debugging shows TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function
http://test2.gutscheindevil.de/wp-content/themes/gutscheindevil/includes/js/jquery-ui/ui.core.js?ver=1.8.5
Line 13

Comment: i also having a problem to properly position the autocomplete box. Its always top left

Comment: @theo69 - no idea, it looks like you might not be including jQuery first

Answer (score 0):

before pushing data into the array do

WhateverString.replace("&amp;", "&");

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, ideally you would combat this at the source, by changing your data. If for some reason that won't work for you however, you can also [extend the widget](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/) to decode any html entities before rendering items.

To do this could would tap into [_renderItem( ul, item )](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem), [demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/rLzDu).

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        var label = $('<div />').html(item.label).text();

        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( $( "<a>" ).text(label) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
});
```